# What is the radius of the small circle relative to the big circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

In the image above, what is the ratio of the small circle's radius to the big circle's radius.

A hasty answer would be $\dfrac{1}{4}$, but if you look closely, you'll find the small circle actually goes through $5$ rotations before getting back to the original point.  Therefore, I claim that the ratio is $\dfrac{1}{5}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems the smaller circle makes $4$ rotations so the circumference of the smaller circle is $4$ times smaller. So $2 \pi r_1 \cdot 4 = 2 \pi r_2$ meaning $$ 8 r_1 = 2 r_2 $$ or $4 r_1 = r_2$ with $r_1$ the radius of the smaller circle and $r_2$ the radius of the bigger circle.

Comment: @prcssngnr  Don't forget that the small circle also rotates about itself (its own center) once through the whole rotation about the big circle.

Comment: [[A]] "Is this correct?" : NO ! It is not ! [[B]] Earth rotates around in 24 hours & takes 365 Days to go around the Sun : Does that makes Sun EQUAL 365 times Earth ? No ! [[C]] Imagine your red Circle shrinks to a Point , then your green circle goes around with 1 rotation : Will that make red Dot EQUAL green Circle ? No ! [[D]] You should Compare Perimeters & lengths , not rotations & angles.

Comment: @HosamH I see what you mean, but still the question is about the ratio of the radii which can be deduced from the fact that the ratio of the circumferences is $4$. Intuitively if you flatten out the big circle the small circle will still roll $4$ times to reach the end.

Comment: @HosamH: FYI, the term-of-art for the drawn curve is [epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid).

Comment: Also see the [Coin rotation paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_rotation_paradox).

Comment: @Hosam H: You are looking at the rotation angle ratio, but your question was about the ratio of generating diameters or radii.

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks, I understand now.  Upvoted your answer. [+1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rolling out $4$ circumferences of the small circle for every once around the circumference of the large circle. This means that the ratio of the circumferences is $4$; which, in turn, means that the ratio of the diameters is $4$.

[image]

Perhaps straightening out the large circle might make this clearer.

[image]

The extra rotation of the small circle comes from the small circle going around the larger circle. Notice that when the large circle is straightened out, the small circle only rotates $4$ times.

Comment: No. it actually rotates $5$ times.  It's your choice of the length of the red line that makes the confusion.

Comment: No, the red line is exactly the length of the circumference of the large circle in relation to the green circle. It might settle the matter to simply measure the diameters of the circles in the animation. You will then see that the ratio of the diameters is $4$.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 8):

Although the smaller circle completes five revolutions, it lays off its circumference on the circumference of the larger circle only four times. Therefore, since a circle’s radius is proportional to its circumference, the radius of the smaller circle is $\frac{1}{4}$th the radius of the larger circle.

Comment: What it lays off  (in what appears to be one revolution) is not its circumference.  It is greater than its circumference.  Look closely as the red dot completes one revolution.  It is not touching the big circle yet.

Comment: Yes, it has returned  to the “6 o’clock” position in relation to the viewer, but it has not yet rolled out its full circumference on the big circle.  The wheel has not yet completed a full revolution on the the road.

Answer (score 3):

We assume the red dot on the small circle is fixed at a particular point on the small circle. From the image you provided we count that the red dot touches the big circle exactly $4$ times before coming back to the start location. From this we conclude that the circumference of the big circle is $4$ times greater than the small circle, i.e.:

$$ 2 \pi r_1 \cdot 4 = 2 \pi r_2 $$

And so we conclude that the radius of the big circle $r_2$ is $4$ times greater than the radius of the small circle $r_1$, or $ 4r_1 = r_2 $.

Comment: No.  I don't think that's correct.

Comment: If the red dot is fixed at some point on the small circle it must be that $4r_1 = r_2$. What is the issue with the reasoning above?

Answer (score 1):

When the ratio of radii (big fixed to small rolling circles) is $n,$ the number of epicycloids produced is also $ n = R/r$.

When a circle rolls on another circle of equal radius,$ ~n=1,$ it is a cardioid.

For the shown case of the four drawn epicycloids, $n=4.$

( We should not confuse with the case of rotation angles at respective centers where the ration is $\frac{R}{r}+1$).